# explain what's wrong with delete and destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not able to delete the data stored in the database pls help?

this is my sages_controller.rb

```
def delete
   @sage = Sage.find(params[:id])
end

  def destroy
    Sage.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to '/thanksss'
  end
```

this is my delete.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @sage do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :Name %>
    <%= f.text_field :Name %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.label :Email %>
    <%= f.text_field :Email %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.label :Address %>
    <%= f.text_field :Address %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.label :Number %>
    <%= f.text_field :Number %>
    <br/>
    <%= f.submit 'Delete' %>
<% end %>
```

this is my routes.rb

```
get 'sages/delete/:id'=> 'sages#delete'
delete 'sages/delete/:id'=> 'sages#destroy'
```

Comment: `form_for` uses `post` or `patch` http methods while you need `delete` method. BTW what is the purpose of your form anyway?

Comment: ohk can you give some details @Marek Lipka

Comment: if you see the delete action. you are just fetching the object from db, not calling delete on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create form for this. `button_to` should work

```
<%= button_to "delete", @sage, :method => :delete, :class => :destroy %>
```

this will internally generate a `form` with `DELETE` method, opposed to default `GET` method like below,

```
<%= form_for @sage, :method => :delete do  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,
Change your button to link,

```
<%= link_to "delete", @sage, :method=>:delete %>
```

And change your routes file to,

```
resources :sages,only: [:new,:create,:edit, :update, :delete]
get 'sages/delete/:id'=> 'sages#delete'
```

Change your delete method like,

```
def delete
  @sage = Sage.find(params[:id])
  destroy
end
```